# Redirecting to AMP Version of a webpage (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amp-html

I'm using Google's AMP in a project, and want to redirect to the AMP version of a resource when a user creates a new resource.

I have a model named `Guide`. My controller `create` action, looks like this - pretty basic:

```
  def create
    console
@guide = Guide.new(guide_params)

    if @guide.save
    redirect_to @guide
else
    redirect_to :action => "new", notice: "Something went wrong, sorry!"
end
```

end

How do I make redirect_to go to the AMP version of that page? e.g. instead of going to `/guides/12345`, it goes to `/guides/12345.amp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the AMP version of the resource you should add the `format: :amp` option to the url of the resource.

```
redirect_to guide_path(@guide, format: :amp)
```

for a full blown implementation you should consider adding a gem like [rails_amp](https://andycroll.com/ruby/amp-project-pages-ruby-on-rails/)